# PHP Variable reference inside a text value of mysql and return value

Tags: php, sql, variables, replace

I'm trying to replace a variable reference with its value when I receive it from the database.

Exanple; 
(stored in a database field)

```
Hello, {$Query['name']}.<br /><br />How are u doing today?
```

That text string which is inside the database when I receive it, it doesn't replace `$Query['name']` with its value. But it shows exactly how it's stored inside the database.

Is there a way, I can store multiple variable references inside the database and return it and replace the variable name with its value?

I use this for creating text templates.

EDIT:
Not sure if I explained it well, but the variable reference is stored inside the database. I'm using PHP to receive it, and when I do and echo it, it echoes the variable name instead of the defined value on that page.

Comment: What type of file is this in?

Comment: you have to put the variable inside of a <?php echo command.

Comment: It's just a PHP script

Comment: ex: <?php echo $Query['name] ?>

Comment: Keep in mind that you are not storing the "variable" in the database, you are storing a reference to the variable.

Comment: @EternalHour I will update my question with  'Reference'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

J Quest, you can try to use eval (http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

`eval("\$str = \"Hello {$Query['name']}. How are u doing today?\";"); echo $str;`

or better yet, do what EternalHour recommended

Comment: This gave me a Parse error on the syntax <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '&lt;', expecting end of file in <b>/api.php(223) : eval()'d code</b> on line <b>1</b><br />

Answer (score 2):

Store in your DB like this:

> `Hello, {name}.<br /><br />How are u doing today?`

To replace the value:

`echo str_replace("{name}", $Query['name'], $db_string);`

Comment: Can I do this dynamically with different names?

Comment: Yes, the value becomes whatever is returned in `$Query['name']`

Comment: I'm going to try it, but I meant, can I use this with different variable names?

Comment: I'd recommend putting the allowed list of names in an array, then loop over the array: `foreach (['name', 'title', 'description'] as $var) { str_replace('{' . $var . '}', $Query[$var], $string); }`

Comment: It's a good idea, @AlexHowansky. This was meant to be very simplified.

Comment: Note you can also pass arrays as the first and second params of `str_replace()`, so you can do it in one shot: `str_replace(['{one}', '{two}', '{three}'], [$Query['one'], $Query['two'], $Query['three']], $string)`

Comment: @AlexHowansky what do you recommend for +/- 10 variables based on performance? The foreach or the one without foreach?

Comment: If you are doing only one query to get the strings from the db there shouldn't be a performance issue.

Comment: To do it dynamically you need to `foreach` the `$Query` array.

Answer (score 1):

To use your existing data, you need to force PHP to evaluate `$Query['name']` as a variable. Assuming `$string` comes from the database:

```
eval('echo "'.$string.'";');
//or
eval('$string = "'.$string.'";');
echo $string;
```

As an alternative to using `eval`, you can use a simple template engine approach. 
 If you store your data like this:

```
Hello, {name}.<br /><br />How are u doing today?
```

Then just loop `$Query` and replace the keys with values:

```
foreach($Query as $search => $replace) {
    $string = str_replace("{{$search}}", $replace, $string);
}
```

`str_replace` can work with arrays, but we need to add the `{}` to the keys.  They are doubled `{{}}` because they have special meaning in double-quoted strings and we want the literal characters.  You can also use `'{'.$search.'}'`

Comment: What is the added value of the `foreach` when the `eval()` itself did the job?

Comment: `eval` has it's place but can be very dangerous if you pass in untrusted data.  The `str_replace` is actually a very common way to implement templating as you're doing.

Comment: Ah, I see, with the `foreach` I only allow to use existing keys from the array `$query` so they cannot use different variables in my script. But what isn't clear for me in your answer is; do I need to use the `eval()` when I use the `foreach`. I don't think so.

Comment: No, I will make it more clear.  I gave 2 ways, the `str_replace` being the preferred and `eval` in case you have a db full of data already that you can't or don't want to change.

Answer (score -1):

In PHP you can display a variable by using the following:

```
Hello, <?php echo $Query['name']?>.<br /><br />How are u doing today?
```

Comment: I know how I can echo a variable name, and defining it. I just have trouble with how PHP react to variable names stored inside the database.

Comment: Are you saying the value of the `$Query` variable is not what you expect it to be?

Comment: The string above is stored inside the database, when I echo the string form the database it shows exactly the variable names instead of the variable values that are defined on that specific page.